# Algorithm for fragmenting data into packets

Tags: algorithm, networking, bin-packing

Lets just say I want to fragment some data units into packets (max size per packet is lets say 1024 bytes). Each data unit can be of variable size, say:

```
a = 20 bytes
b = 1000 bytes
c = 10 bytes
d = 800 bytes
```

Can anyone please suggest any efficient algorithm to create packets with such random data efficiently utilizing the bandwidth? I cannot split the individual data units into bytes...they go whole inside a packet.

**EDIT:** The ordering of data units is of no concern!

Comment: Is the order important (i.e. `c` must be in a package after `a`)? If the answer to it is "no" - this is [binpacking problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which is NP-Hard.

Comment: Dude, yes and yes and yes, you are awesome! Write it as answer and if you have anything to add, and then I would mark it as answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways, depending on your requirements and how much time you want to spend on it. The general problem, as @amit mentioned in comments, is NP-Hard. But you can get *some* improvement with some simple changes.

Before we go there, are you sure you really need to do this? Most networking layers have a packet-sized (or larger) buffer. When you write to the network, it puts your data in that buffer. If you don't fill the buffer completely, the code will delay briefly before sending. If you add more data during that delay, the new data is added to the buffer. The buffer is sent once it fills, or after the delay timeout expires.

So if you have a loop that writes one byte at a time to the network, it's not like you'll be creating a large number of one-byte packets.

On the receiving side, the lowest level networking layer receives an entire packet, but there's no guarantee that your call to receive the data will get the entire packet. That is, the sender might send an 800 byte packet, but on the receiving end the first call to read might only return 50 or 273 bytes.

This depends, of course, at what level you're reading the data. If you're talking about something like Java or .NET, where your interface to the network stack is through a socket, you almost certainly can't guarantee that a call to `socket.Read()` will return an entire packet.

Now, if you *can* guarantee that every call to read returns an entire packet, then the easiest way to pack things would be to serialize everything into one big buffer and then send it out in multiple 1,024-byte packets. You'll want to create a header at the front of the first packet that says how many total bytes will be sent, so the receiver knows what to expect. The result will be a bunch of 1,024-byte packets, potentially followed by a final packet that is somewhat smaller.

If you want to make sure that a data object is fully contained within a single packet, then you have to do something like:

```
add a to buffer
if remaining buffer < size of b
    send buffer
    clear buffer
add b to buffer
if remaining buffer < size of c
    send buffer     
    clear buffer
add c to buffer
... etc ...
```

Comment: Jim, thanks for your answer! If only life were that simple...I am dealing with a protocol which needs fragmentation right at the application layer. It packages two different types of "data units" and sends them in a packet which is of limited size. And these data units cannot be altered. So my problem is exactly the Bin packing problem. Moreover these nice concepts like serializing also wont work...thats how weird the protocol is. I am only working on the server side so cant bend the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple JavaScript pseudo code. The packets will stay ordered and the bandwidth will be used optimally.

```
packets = [];

PACKET_SIZE = 1024;
currentPacket = [];

function write(data) {
  var len = currentPacket.length + data.length;
  if(len < PACKET_SIZE) {
    currentPacket = currentPacket.concat(data);
  } else if(len === PACKET_SIZE) {
    packets.push(currentPacket.concat(data));
    currentPacket = [];
  } else { // if(len > PACKET_SIZE) {
    packets.push(currentPacket);
    currentPacket = data;
  }
}
function flush() {
  if(currentPacket.length > 0) {
    packets.push(currentPacket);
    currentPacket = [];
  }
}

write(data20bytes);
write(data1000bytes);
write(data10bytes);
write(data800bytes);
flush();
```

**EDIT** Since you have all of the data chunks and you want to optimally package them out of order (bin packing) then you left with trying every permutation of the chunks for an exact answer or compromising with an best guess/first fit type algorithm.